# ¿Cómo obtener valores en un select option en angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, html-select, frontend

estoy tratando de obtener un valor de la base de datos y ponerlo en un select cuando el usuario actualiza los campos en un formulario, pero solo se muestra "seleccione empresa" y no el valor que le corresponde.

lo que echo es lo siguiente:
HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-6 form-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group">Empresa</span>
  <select  class="form-select campo-select" (change)="ChangeValue($event)">
  <option [value]="emp.idEmpresa" *ngFor="let emp of empresa" >
     {{emp.nombreComercial}}
  </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Typescript

```
  SelectValue:any;

  ChangeValue(e){
    console.log(e.target.value)
    this.SelectValue=e.target.value;
  }

    this.http.get<any>(environment.API_URL+'usuario')
    .subscribe(data=>{
      this.usuarios=data;
    });

  editClick(ce:any){
    this.modalTitle="Editar usuario";
    this.idUsuario=ce.idUsuario;
    this.usuario=ce.usuario;
    this.idEmpresa=ce.idEmpresa;
  }

  updateClick(){
    var val={
      idUsuario:this.idUsuario,
      usuario:this.usuario,
      idEmpresa:this.SelectValue,
    };
   this.http.put(environment.API_URL+'usuario',val)
    .subscribe(res=>{
    });
  }
```

Comment: ¿Y en dónde se asignan los valores de `empresa`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso el problema que estas teniendo es que dentro de la función ChangeValue no estas asignandolo al modelo que le corresponde. Pero lo mejor es hacerlo por ngform o por reactive forms.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <select formControlName="empresa">
        <option *ngFor="let emp of empresa" [ngValue]="emp">
          {{emp.nombreComercial}}
        </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Y en el .ts deberías declarar

```
form = new FormGroup({
    empresa: new FormControl(),
});
```

Si quieres usar la forma de acceder mediante el template el codigo sería

```
<form #f="ngForm">
      <select name="empresa" ngModel>
        <option value="" disabled>Elige una empresa</option>
        <option *ngFor="let emp of empresa" [ngValue]="emp">
          {{emp.nombreComercial}}
        </option>
      </select>
</form>
```

Aquí esta la documentación oficial de angular https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor

El evento `(change)="ChangeValue($event)"` lo puedes seguir utilizando de la misma manera para actualizar cualquier otra variable que necesites.